# Adding a HeadItem to LazyVerticalGrid without it being wrapped in ElevatedCard

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, card

I want to add a head item to my LazyVerticalGrid, but without it being wrapped inside the ElevatedCard. Here is my code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AppGrid(
    apps: List<CommonApp>,
    hybridApps: List<TagWithHybridAppList>,
    newsData: List<String>,
    appSwitch: Boolean,
    onSwitchClick: () -> Unit,
    onAppItemClick: (Any) -> Unit
) {
        ElevatedCard(
            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
                defaultElevation = 6.dp
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(10.dp, 15.dp, 10.dp, 10.dp)
                .background(LColors.White)
        ) {
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                columns = GridCells.Fixed(4),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(if (appSwitch) 1300.dp else 80.dp)
            ) {
                if (newsData.isNotEmpty()) {
                    item(span = { GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan) }) {
                        LBanner(bannerData = newsData)
                    }
                }
                if (apps.isNotEmpty()) {
                    items(apps) { app ->
                        MyApp(app, onAppItemClick)
                    }
                    item {
                        AppSwitchBtn(switch = appSwitch, onClick = {
                            onSwitchClick()
                        })
                    }

                }
        }
```

While this code achieves the purpose of scrolling together with the grid content, it is also wrapped within the background of the card. I only need MyApp and AppSwitchBtn to be wrapped inside the Card.